# Not sure why I am recieving an Auth0 invalid grant Error when exchanging my authentication code for an access token

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs, authorization, auth0

I am building a server application using NestJs, I am 'faking' the client side user authentification by running 2 apps in my nest application, one for auth0 to attach login and logout routes to, and one for the actual server application.

When I try to use the access code returned from the user authentification (this is taken from the network park of dev tools, where I am getting a 301 response with a code and state) and have it request an access token from my API im getting this error

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}%

I have been stuck on this for about half a day and cant seem to figure out whats going wrong.

this is the request im using to get the access token:

```
`curl --request POST \
\--url 'https://\<domain_name\>.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token' \
\--header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
\--data grant_type=authorization_code \
\--data 'client_id= {My client ID}' \
\--data 'client_secret={My client secret}' \
\--data 'code={code returned from authenticating user}' \\ 
\--data 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback'
```

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}%`

I have checked and my client ID and secret is the same in my auth0 config for my client auth set up, so is my callback URL, im really lost here!

(im using an express app and converter in my main.js for the client side)

```
expressApp.use(
    auth({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_SESSION,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
    authRequired: false,
    auth0Logout: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_APP_CLIENTID,
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_URL,
    authorizationParams: {
    response_type: 'code',
    audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIANCE,
    },
   }),
);
```

If anyone has any advice it would be extremely appriciated <3